# Is it possible to get near to me from current location in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-fragments, dictionary

Hi I am facing problem regarding location in android.Actually my requirement is, how i will get  "near to me" from current location in android.and Please tell me the best way to find out near to me.and please tell me the tutorial,blog spots and any other options which i get these near to me..